# How to make the Messages panel to disappear after I successfully compile a project?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

In Delphi XE, how to make the Messages panel to disappear after I successfully compile a project?
That was the default behavior in Delphi 7. In Delphi XE it says 'success' and it leaves that box open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XE, Messages is not a message box but a dockable window and as such it won't disappear automatically.

Workaround: Close the Messages window and save the desktop (click on the button next to the Classic Undocked in the toolbar). After each recompile you can then reselect saved desktop by clicking into drop-down list with desktop name (Classic Undocked) and pressing Enter on the keyboard.

Comment: Hi Gabr. I hope there is a more convenient way to make that panel automatically go away. Until them I will use your trick. I don't get why Delphi XE leaves it open while Delphi 7 closed it all the time...

Comment: @thelight: Because the IDE in XE is a complete rewrite of Delphi 7 IDE and behaves completely different. I think your best bet is to get used to "docked" layout. Check http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2011/01/delphi-on-wide-screen.html for some examples on how to configure XE in docked mode.

Comment: I have a wide screen and I already use the docked layout. But indeed I could crowd few more panels on screen :) Thanks for that link.

Answer (score 1):

Like Delphi 7 you can check the box under the window of compiler process.

look t the picture
[image: compiler message]